# SFML TCP problems

Tags: c++, sfml

What's wrong with the following code snippets?

the following is a snippet of the client side program code:

```
   while (!done)
    {
        std::cout << "Creating connection" << std::endl;
        sf::TcpSocket socket;
        sf::Socket::Status status = socket.connect("192.168.0.5", 53000);
        if (status != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            std::cout << "Client Error" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Created" << std::endl;
        char data[100] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
        system("pause");
        if (socket.send(data, 100) != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            std::cout << "Client Error : Couldn't send data" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

This code sends the data correctly in alternating steps.

How do I fix it?

also, `system(pause)` is used to generate a delay.

the following is a snippet of the server program code:

```
while (!done)
{
    sf::TcpListener listener;

    // bind the listener to a port
    if (listener.listen(53000) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        // error...
    }

    // accept a new connection
    sf::TcpSocket client;
    if (listener.accept(client) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        // error...
        std::cout << "Error" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {       
        std::cout << "New client connected: " << client.getRemoteAddress() << std::endl;
        char data[100];
        std::size_t received;

        // TCP socket:
        if (client.receive(data, 100, received) != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            // error...
        }
        std::cout << "Received " << received << " bytes: " << data << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Ready" << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to the server everytime? TCP is not connectionless. You connect once and all you have to do is to check if the connection is still alive. If its not just destroy the socket. And try to reconnect. And the listener must be bind only once.

Comment: @Azarus Thank you saved me from going insane :D